# MYSQL pulling two column from one table using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to use JOIN but it seems I am only getting half of the result. Below are the tables and required output.

[image]

I'm not getting any error.
When I used JOIN it only shows the `approver1`. So What I did is:

```
SELECT tb1.*, tb2.name AS a1, tb3.name AS a2 
FROM   table1 tb1 
       LEFT JOIN approver tb2 
       ON tb1.approve1 = tb2.id 
       LEFT JOIN approver tb3 
       ON tb1.approver2 = tb2.id
```

Any help or clue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you getting any error messages? if so, please post them

Comment: Post your wrong query and we can fix together

Comment: im not getting any error, when I used JOIN it only shows the approver1. So What I did is, `select tb1.*, tb2.name AS a1, tb3.name AS a2 FROM table1 tb1 LEFT JOIN approver tb2 ON tb1.approve1 = tb2.id LEFT JOIN approver tb3 ON tb1.approver2 = tb2.id`

Comment: @genpet: Whelp, looks to me like you've got one or more typos and a whale of a copy-paste error. Where do we go from here? Have you tried any of the solutions offered below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select empname, ap_1.name, ap_2.name from Employee 
left join Approver as ap_a on (Employee.approver1 = ap_1.id)
left join Approver as ap_b on (Employee.approver2 = ap_2.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `LEFT JOIN` to fetch rows where there is no associated approver. For example. `Dwade Curtis` doesn't have an associated `approver2`

```
SELECT e.emp_name, a1.name as ap1, a2.name as ap2
FROM employee e 
LEFT JOIN approver a1 ON (a1.id=e.approver1)
LEFT JOIN approver a2 ON (a2.id=e.approver2)
```

[This](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) is a good visual explanation of SQL JOINs